# How to deal with school grades that are labelled '0' because of student grouping according to ability in a Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, prediction

I'm binary classifying student performance at university with Keras and Tensorflow, amongst others, with two inputs 'Math_A' (high school grade in course Mathematics A) & 'Math_B' (high school grade in course Mathematics B).

[find an example of the table with the grades here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWocY.png) (not allowed to show images yet)

In this school system students are [streamed](https://wehavekids.com/education/STREAMINGThe-benefits-of-streaming-in-secondary-schools) to different classes (A or B) according their math ability. Now everbody that attending class 'Math_A' obviously does not receive a grade for class 'Math_B' so varyingly grades are labelled '0'  at every other observation. (labelling them NaN is not the best solution either, as far as I understand from reading a few other questions here)

From my understanding a Neural Network would now interpret this as grade '0' (=very bad) and adjust the weights accordingly but I would like to tell it that this grade is only zero (or NaN) because the student attended the other class and got his math grade there.

My question: How can I circumvent that the Neural Network missinterprets the data?

Thank you for your help!

(PS: Pls be gentle on me, I'm fairly new to all of this)

Answer (score 0):

A well trained neural network will be able dechiper this. If in doubt, use a recurrent LSTM algorithm and train over at least 10 epoches of substantial differential data.

Comment: Thx, nice to hear. I only got a total of about 3000 observations which are 70:30 balanced. KFold cross validation gives me about 70% accuracy but so far I think it's because the rest of the features are not significant enough. Only got one more continous variable 'avg total school grade' and rest are binary features.

Comment: Can you link the dataset please

Comment: I would love too but unfortunately I can't because I signed an NDA. It's sensible university data and they made me sign it.
Could you answer me one more question? Would it be more sensible to keep the grades labelled zero or as 'NaN'?

Comment: I try to describe the columns so you have an idea even though I know it's not very helpful:

Four binary variables (0/1 if somebody deregistered before end of semester, 0/1 if somebody is registered for next semester, gender, 0/1 if somebody switched program after first semester) , three "grade" variables (Math_A, Math_B, avg school grade), three column one hot encoded "origin" variable (native, EU, non-EU), six column one hot encoded "name of program" variable.

Target feature is also binary